# Add parameter to the Submit link of the Smart capture

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture

Is it possible to add a parameter to the smart capture link via AMP script?

I have created a page including Smart capture and passed a parameter via email using AMP Script to the landing page and stored it into hidden field.

Now I want to add this parameter to the Submit URL provided by Smart capture,

Comment: Why would you need to add this parameter to the submit url?

Comment: This parameter is a token . with the token attached to the URL, there is no need to login to the page page the Submit is leading to.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a need to modify the Smart Capture form's submit link. Hidden attribute values will be included during form submission automatically if their initial values are set to capture them from the `CloudPagesURL`-generated link, e.g., `RequestParameter('my_token')`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.   

the token will be attached to the Data Extension, however It won`t be attached to the URL of the Submit Link. I tried to add the token as parameter, does not function either

Comment: @kalalewe Smart Capture submits a POST request (not GET), so attaching your parameter to the submit link wouldn't work anyway. Is the token not being inserted into the DE after form submission following the answer above?

Comment: yes, the token is added to the DE, this is working fine.

thanks for the hint,  that attaching the parameter to the submit wouldn't`t work. 
Thats exactly what I wanted to do and tried to find a solution.